# TypeError: Singleton array 0 cannot be considered a valid collection

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to develop a confusion matrix for my multiclass model. However, I am getting a type error during the process.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.datasets import cifar10

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
from keras.utils import np_utils
y_train=np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10)
y_test=np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10)
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')/255
y_train=y_train.astype('float32')/255
y_train_labels=np.argmax(y_train, axis=1)
from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten
def mod(activation):
  model=Sequential()

  model.add(Conv2D(3,kernel_size=3,activation='relu',input_shape=(32,32,3)))
  model.add(Conv2D(3,kernel_size=3,activation='relu'))
  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dense(10,activation='softmax'))

  return model
import sklearn.metrics as metrics

for activations in ["relu", "tanh", "sigmoid"]:
  for epochs in [1,10,15]:
    model_eval=mod(activations)


    model_eval.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
    y_pred=model_eval.fit(x_train,y_train,validation_data=(x_test,y_test),epochs=epochs)
    y_pred_labels=np.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)
    confusion_matrix = metrics.confusion_matrix(y_true=y_train_labels, y_pred=y_pred_labels)
```

Here is the error that I am getting -

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-512cdec6aaaf> in <module>()
      7     y_pred=model_eval.fit(x_train,y_train,validation_data=(x_test,y_test),epochs=epochs)
      8     y_pred_labels=np.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)
----> 9     confusion_matrix = metrics.confusion_matrix(y_true=y_train_labels, y_pred=y_pred_labels)  # shape=(12, 12)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in _num_samples(x)
    144         if len(x.shape) == 0:
    145             raise TypeError("Singleton array %r cannot be considered"
--> 146                             " a valid collection." % x)
    147         # Check that shape is returning an integer or default to len
    148         # Dask dataframes may not return numeric shape[0] value

TypeError: Singleton array 0 cannot be considered a valid collection.
```

This may also be an inefficient/wrong way to code in the confusion matrix. If so, please do direct me in the correct path.

Comment: what is the shape of `y_train_labels ` and `y_pred_labels `?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reshape both `y_train_labels` and `y_pred_labels` to (N,1) instead of (N,):

```
y_train_labels = y_train_labels.reshape(-1,1)
y_pred_labels  = y_pred_labels.reshape(-1,1)
```